# Finding a pair with a given sum in a sorted array - is there a correctness proof?

Tags: algorithm

I saw the 2 pointer algorithm in dozens of posts, i.e:

```
l = 0;
r = n - 1;

while (l < r)
    sum = A[l] + A[r];
    if (sum == expected) return true;
    elif (sum < expected) l++;
    else r--;
```

I know it works. I even solved it myself in an interview. But I couldn't find anywhere a correctness proof, or even an intuitive explanation to why it works.

Can someone provide an explanation or link to one?

Thanks

Comment: what's initial value of `l`, `r`? 0 and n-1?

Comment: @shole yes, l=0 and r=n-1

Comment: The loop is missing, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine 2D array where `B[i,j] = A[i] + A[j]`. Note that all the numbers in the array are in increasing order from left to right and from top to bottom.

Set `l=0, r=n-1` - this is right top corner of the whole 2D array, element B[0,n-1], and start search.

For every index pair (l, r) we can see three opportunities (I omit check for pointer intersections):

Sum to found `X = B[l,r]` => So we have found needed indexes. Exit.

`X < B[l, r]` => Due to the sorted order of  column, all elements of this column are too large, so we can exclude this column, and decrement r (move left)

`X > B[l, r]` => Due to the sorted order of row, all elements of this row are too small, so we can exclude this row, and increment l (move down)

Note that at every step we stay in the right top corner of subarray with possible solutions, that is why two last cases work

Comment: Why `X < B[l, r]`, you cannot go upward (decreases `l` by one)? Similar to the other case. Thanks :)

Comment: Because at that moment we already have excluded top lines and right columns. Think about very first step - we are in [0, n-1] corner, there is nothing above and right. Next step excludes (cuts off) either row or column and we again stay at the corner.